# Permission for Facebook developer id - to create app/etc

Tags: facebook

Is there a concept of a developer ID on Facebook : an id that can be used to setup apps/etc ? Their policy state that one can get an id with their permission. If this possible then what does anybody know the process for achieving this ?

In the same lines, is there a similar concept of a tester or support id ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A Google search query of "facebook developer id" returns this as the 3rd result: [How to Get Your Facebook Developers ID](http://www.ehow.com/how_8506809_facebook-developers-id.html). It was faster to do the Google search and give the link than explain it over again here. When you go to developers.facebook.com and register for an app account you will be given IDs. The article explains it all step by step setting it up on Facebook. Also in response to your question about the testing and support id. I could not figure anything out about an actual support id, but you may want to check out this [link on Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/) which explains how Test User accounts are associated with Apps.

Comment: Thanks Cory ! This link might be old, since Facebook does not include creating Developer ID as part of creating new apps (I have tried various combinations, but never managed to get the steps explained in that link to show up). The Test User Account link was insightful. Thanks for that.